# Which data structure will be suitable for storing three related values? And how to implement?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I have

```
[0][11011] = 0.7; 
[32][11101] = 0.3
```

Where the first value is integer position, second unique character id, and third is the value of this stucture itself. 
Which data structure will be suitable for storing three values?

---

Suppose I have set1:

```
[0][11111] = 0.5; 
[16][11110] = 0.5; 
[32][11011] = 0.5; 
[48][10111] = 0.5; 

And I have set2 
[0][11011] = 0.7; 
[1][11101] = 0.3
```

I want get string value from set2 11011 search in the set1, if it matches for example on position 32, then assign to that structure value 0.7 instead of 0.5.
So I need to know which data structure can be useful for this. And how to implement?

Comment: Check [this page from the Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html) for an example implementation.

Comment: What's the requirements from this collection?

Comment: First value is integer value index. Like in array.
Second value is unique String id. And last is numeric value. 
I will have two similar those structures. LAter I want to get String id and search in array which looks like this format [int][11111]
So if the string pattern matches I want assign to that Array certain value.

Comment: so while retrieving what values you will be using? index or string? or both?

Comment: I edited my question and added example. String value I will use for as query in the other set2. If that string will be matched with another string in set2 then I assign value to that set2 instance from what I retieved current set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java its easy to wrap these three values in an Object.

For example:

```
public class TestObject {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private int id;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Here you have an Object of Type TestObject that wraps in two values(two [primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) types `int` and `String` - You can Wrap in any type of Object in exactly the same way).
You can set and get these values once the Object is [initialized](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html)(instantiated).

```
TestObject obj = new TestObject();
obj.setId(1);
obj.setName("George");
```

Getting values back :

```
String name= obj.getName();
int id=obj.getId();
```

In your case you can include the three values in an Object like this (POJO) and then you can include a lot of these Objects in a [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/index.html).
An easy and efficient Collection Type IMO is the [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) though this is not restrictive.

You can add Objects in an `ArrayList` like this:

```
java.util.ArrayList<TestObject> list = new ArrayList<TestObject>();
list.add(obj);
```

You can retrieve Objects from the list by looping it like this:

```
for(TestObject x:list){
  int id=x.getId();
  String name=x.getName();
}
```